# Select items in a list that contain criteria #2

Tags: list-manipulation

In List:

```
Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, 4]
```

How can I select all items that contain only two "9"?

Result:

> {{1, 1, 9, 9}, {1, 2, 9, 9}, {1, 3, 9, 9}, {1, 4, 9, 9}, {1, 9, 1, 9}
>   ... {9, 9, 4, 3}, {9, 9, 4, 4}}

Comment: Try `Select[alist, Count[#, 9] == 2 &]`.

Comment: Thanks! b.gates.you.know.what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list=Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, 4];
Cases[_?(Count[#, 9] == 2&)] @ list
Pick[list, Lookup[Counts /@ list, 9, 0] - 2, 0]
```

both give

> {{1, 1, 9, 9}, {1, 2, 9, 9}, {1, 3, 9, 9}, {1, 4, 9, 9}, {1, 9, 1, 
>     9}, {1, 9, 2, 9}, {1, 9, 3, 9}, {1, 9, 4, 9}, {1, 9, 9, 1}, {1, 9, 
>     9, 2}, {1, 9, 9, 3}, {1, 9, 9, 4}, {2, 1, 9, 9}, {2, 2, 9, 9}, {2, 
>     3, 9, 9}, {2, 4, 9, 9}, {2, 9, 1, 9}, {2, 9, 2, 9}, {2, 9, 3, 
>     9}, {2, 9, 4, 9}, {2, 9, 9, 1}, {2, 9, 9, 2}, {2, 9, 9, 3}, {2, 9, 
>     9, 4}, {3, 1, 9, 9}, {3, 2, 9, 9}, {3, 3, 9, 9}, {3, 4, 9, 9}, {3, 
>     9, 1, 9}, {3, 9, 2, 9}, {3, 9, 3, 9}, {3, 9, 4, 9}, {3, 9, 9, 
>     1}, {3, 9, 9, 2}, {3, 9, 9, 3}, {3, 9, 9, 4}, {4, 1, 9, 9}, {4, 2, 
>     9, 9}, {4, 3, 9, 9}, {4, 4, 9, 9}, {4, 9, 1, 9}, {4, 9, 2, 9}, {4, 
>     9, 3, 9}, {4, 9, 4, 9}, {4, 9, 9, 1}, {4, 9, 9, 2}, {4, 9, 9, 
>     3}, {4, 9, 9, 4}, {9, 1, 1, 9}, {9, 1, 2, 9}, {9, 1, 3, 9}, {9, 1, 
>     4, 9}, {9, 1, 9, 1}, {9, 1, 9, 2}, {9, 1, 9, 3}, {9, 1, 9, 4}, {9, 
>     2, 1, 9}, {9, 2, 2, 9}, {9, 2, 3, 9}, {9, 2, 4, 9}, {9, 2, 9, 
>     1}, {9, 2, 9, 2}, {9, 2, 9, 3}, {9, 2, 9, 4}, {9, 3, 1, 9}, {9, 3, 
>     2, 9}, {9, 3, 3, 9}, {9, 3, 4, 9}, {9, 3, 9, 1}, {9, 3, 9, 2}, {9, 
>     3, 9, 3}, {9, 3, 9, 4}, {9, 4, 1, 9}, {9, 4, 2, 9}, {9, 4, 3, 
>     9}, {9, 4, 4, 9}, {9, 4, 9, 1}, {9, 4, 9, 2}, {9, 4, 9, 3}, {9, 4, 
>     9, 4}, {9, 9, 1, 1}, {9, 9, 1, 2}, {9, 9, 1, 3}, {9, 9, 1, 4}, {9, 
>     9, 2, 1}, {9, 9, 2, 2}, {9, 9, 2, 3}, {9, 9, 2, 4}, {9, 9, 3, 
>     1}, {9, 9, 3, 2}, {9, 9, 3, 3}, {9, 9, 3, 4}, {9, 9, 4, 1}, {9, 9, 
>     4, 2}, {9, 9, 4, 3}, {9, 9, 4, 4}}

Comment: @Carbajo, thank you for the accept. But I would go for Coolwater's method; it is several orders faster.

Answer (score 7):

E.g.

```
L = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, 4];

Pick[L, Total[Clip[L, {9, 9}, {0, 0}], {2}], 18]
```

If you need it repeatably, you could make a list of parts

```
parts = Position[L, _?(Count[#, 9] == 2 &), {1}][[All, 1]];
```

and simply write `L[[parts]]`

Answer (score 3):

```
L = Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 9}, 4];

Pick[L, Total /@ UnitStep[L - 8], 2]
```

Or

```
Pick[L, Total /@ UnitBox[L - 9], 2]
```